# Where did the description that acids are sour and bases are bitter come from?

Tags: acid-base, taste

Where did the description that acids are sour and bases are bitter come from? With Arrhenius definition, those descriptions may have fit acids and bases, but with the Lewis definition, I guess they would not really apply.

For example, $\ce{AlCl3}$, a known Lewis acid, does not taste sour but rather "gives water a bitter astringent taste" as stated by PubChem in this [link](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/aluminum_chloride#section=Stability).

Comment: AlCl3 in water hydrolyzes and becomes Bronsted acid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do acids without hydrogen taste sour?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6577/do-acids-without-hydrogen-taste-sour)

Comment: Ok, I edited it so that it won't be the same with that question. :)

Comment: Modifying the content of your question to say something else is prohibited in SE, but I reckon since your new revision *was* a part of your last question this is allowed.